# A probabilistic data structure based on flipping bits with probability `1/2^x` for counting

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, probability, probability-theory

How does this data structure work and what is its application?

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def plus_one(self):
        self.x = self.x + flip(self.x)

    def get(self):
        return 2**self.x #2 raised to the power of x
```

The `flip()` function is a random function that returns 1 with probability `1/2^x` and 0 otherwise.

I suspect that this data structure is somehow related to R. Morris's probabilistic counting algorithm.

The question also mentions that this inequality might be helpful:
`log(E[X]) >= E[log(X)]`

where `E` denotes the expected value.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance.

Comment: This data structure is exactly an implementation of R. Morris' approximate counting algorithm.

Comment: This is approximate counter as already noted. Basically keeps exponent of the number of events